# Unable to connect a docker-contained mongodb with mongo compass

Tags: mongodb, docker, mongoose, mongodb-compass

I have made a mongodb inside a docker container, `.yml` file

```
  mongo:
    image: mongo:5.0
    restart: always
    volumes: 
      - demo-data:/data/db
      - ./mongo-admin.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-admin.js
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: demo
```

It is running and working. I can view the db in mongo express.
It is connected with mongoose in node server.

```
const connection = await mongoose.connect('mongodb://demo:password@mongo:27017/demo', { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, err => {
    if (err) console.log('Error connecting to database', err);
  });
```

I have tried to connect with so many ip, none of them works. All container IP, localhost, 127.0.0.1.

Either authentication error or time out error.

How do I properly connect it step by step.

Updates these string not working-

> mongodb://root:password@mongo:27017/demo
> mongodb://demo:password@mongo:27017/demo
> mongodb://root:password@localhost:27017/demo
> mongodb://root:password@0.0.0.0:27017/demo
> mongodb://root:password@192.168.0.8:27017/demo
> mongodb://root:password@172.0.0.1:27017/demo

run `docker ps` command in window it returns these info

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                    NAMES

dd753046aacb   mongo:5.0            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   24 minutes ago   Up 24 minutes   27017/tcp                demo-server-mongo-1
```

Comment: In your sample, it seems that you mixed up user and database name. Might this be the reason for the auth error?

Answer (score 0):

In your connection string, It seems you have confused between `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME` and `MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE`.

You should change connection string from

```
mongodb://demo:password@mongo:27017/demo
```

to

```
mongodb://root:password@mongo:27017/demo
```

and expose port of `container` if you connect from `host` (By default, you can't use container name, if you connect from host).

```
mongo:
  image: mongo:5.0
  restart: always
  ports:
    - '27017:27017'
  volumes: 
    - demo-data:/data/db
    - ./mongo-admin.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-admin.js
  environment:
    MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
    MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: demo
```

Then, connection string will look like:

```
mongodb://demo:password@localhost:27017/demo
```

or

```
mongodb://demo:password@127.0.0.1:27017/demo
```

Comment: Sorry, it seems the auth error only appears in 0.0.0.0:27017, and both connection string still cause auth error, I am still very much suspicious about building it inside docker changes everything.

Comment: using `mongodb://root:password@mongo:27017/demo` it returns `getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongo`

Comment: while trying out localhost address it returns `connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.0.8:27017`

Comment: Are you connecting from the host or from another container?

Comment: I am connecting from the host. The mongo db is inside container. The mongo compass is outside of the container. It is outside of docker.

Comment: If that so, you need to expose the container port. Let see my edited answer.

Comment: Now they returns authentication error instead. somehow.

Comment: `mongodb://demo:password@127.0.0.1:27017/demo?authSource=admin`

Comment: Please try this connection string to see how it goes.